# Constraint causing exception

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uitableview

I'm creating this constraints inside the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method of a `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
[self.visualEffectView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[visualEffectView(50)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"visualEffectView" : self.visualEffectView}]];
```

This is supposed to constraint a `UIVisualEffectView` to take up the full width of the screen, while being 50 points tall and stick to the bottom of the cell.

However, it displays correctly but causes this exception:

**Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.**

`Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15c7783b0 UIVisualEffectView:0x15c5ae220.top == CustomCell:0x15c5ac140'cell'.topMargin>`

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**UPDATE**

`setup` is called from `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

```
-(void)setup
{
    self.profileImageView = [UIImageView new];
    self.profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];

    [self addSubview:self.profileImageView];
    [self addSubview:self.visualEffectView];

    [self.profileImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.visualEffectView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[profileImageView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"profileImageView" : self.profileImageView}]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[profileImageView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"profileImageView" : self.profileImageView}]];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[visualEffectView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"visualEffectView" : self.visualEffectView}]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[visualEffectView(50)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"visualEffectView" : self.visualEffectView}]];
```

}

Full error message:

```
"(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12c5b2c40 UIVisualEffectView:0x12c753b90.top == CustomCell:0x12c751bb0'cell'.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12c5b2ec0 V:[UIVisualEffectView:0x12c753b90(50)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12c5b2f10 V:[UIVisualEffectView:0x12c753b90]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':CustomCell:0x12c751bb0'cell' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12c5ba110 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[CustomCell:0x12c751bb0'cell'(250)]>"
)"
```

Comment: It conflicts with the other constraints. Please also post those and the whole error from the console.

Comment: You want the `VisualEffectView` to be centred vertically in the cell?

Comment: @Jelly No, I want it pinned to the bottom of the cell with a height of 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra constraint. Replace

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[visualEffectView(50)]|" 
options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"visualEffectView" : self.visualEffectView}]];
```

with

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[visualEffectView(50)]-0-|" 
options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"visualEffectView" : self.visualEffectView}]];
```

Comment: Looks like you're short of the superview character `|`, but replacing it to this: `@"V:|[visualEffectView(50)]-0-|"` removes the exception, but now it's pinned to the top instead of the bottom

Comment: Don't use `|` in the left side, it adds the extra constraint.

Comment: Worked now. Thing with the `|` was strange though - I was reading [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_the_iOS_8_Auto_Layout_Visual_Format_Language_in_Swift) which says "When using the visual format language, the superview of the view for which the constraint is being described is represented by the `|` character."

Comment: **Edit**: I think I understand. So you use the `|` character for where the constraint "connects" to the edge? And because we don't "connect" with the top, we exclude the `|` symbol there?